# Vertical alignment of *all* cells when multirow is used to join some cells

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, multirow

I'm trying to achieve a good vertical alignment for a table whose cells contain alternatively an image or text, but I'm confused by the interaction of `adjustbox` with `multirow`.

The MWE is the following, in which using `\adjustbox{valign=c}{\imma}` instead of `\imma` allows a good alignment with the textual non-multirow cells. Without it, the `\multirow{2}*{\imma} gets good alignment with the various`\imma`, but the textual cells are bottom-aligned.

Since this table mainly contains figures, and short text, the question is basically _how do I get all cells centered vertically? (Horizontal alignment through `r`, `l`, `c`, ... column types should not be affected, preferrably.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\imma}{\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=3cm]{example-image-a}}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lcllc@{}}
    \toprule
    \multirow{2}*{0} & c2f & \multirow{2}*{\imma} & \imma &  \multirow{2}*{\imma} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-2}
    \cmidrule{4-4}
                     & f2c & & \imma &   \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{2}*{1} & c2f &  \imma & \imma &  \multirow{2}*{\imma} \\
    \cmidrule(l){2-4}
                     & f2c &  \imma & \imma &   \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{2}*{2} & c2c &  \adjustbox{valign=c}{\imma} &  &  \adjustbox{valign=c}{\multirow{2}*{\imma}} \\
    \cmidrule(l){2-3}
                     & f2f &  \adjustbox{valign=c}{\imma} &  &   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

which produces
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a fundamental concept to understand: When you wish to align content at the vertical center, you're adjusting the *anchor* point. As a tangible example, consider aligning these two elements vertically:

[image]

```
x \includegraphics[height=1cm,width=3cm]{example-image}
```

Both items above are aligned (vertically) at their baseline. Intuitively one would want to set a vertical alignment for `x` so it sits at the vertical centre of the image, as in

```
\adjustbox{valign=c}{x} \includegraphics[height=1cm,width=3cm]{example-image}
```

However, this does not yield the desired result. Instead, you should adjust the anchor point for the image to its centre (thanks to `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}`):

[image]

```
x \includegraphics[height=1cm,width=3cm,valign=c]{example-image}
```

In fact, it would be better to use

```
\adjustbox{valign=c}{x} \includegraphics[height=1cm,width=3cm,valign=c]{example-image}
```

(but it's not always necessary and may depend on both elements).

With this in mind, here is a slightly different way of constructing the same table without [`multirow`](//ctan.org/pkg/multirow):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\img}{\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=3cm,valign=c]{example-image}}

\begin{tabular}{ @{} l *{4}{@{} c } @{} }
  \toprule
  \adjustbox{valign=c}{0~} & \begin{tabular}{ c }
    \vphantom{\img}c2f \\
    \midrule
    \vphantom{\img}f2c
  \end{tabular} & \img & \begin{tabular}{ c }
    \img \\
    \midrule
    \img
  \end{tabular} & ~\img \\
  \midrule
  \adjustbox{valign=c}{1~} & \multicolumn{3}{@{} c @{}}{\begin{tabular}{ *{3}{c} }
    c2f & \img & \img \\
    \midrule
    f2c & \img & \img
  \end{tabular}} & ~\img \\
  \midrule
  \adjustbox{valign=c}{2~} & \multicolumn{2}{@{} c @{}}{\begin{tabular}{ *{2}{c} }
    c2f & \img \\
    \midrule
    f2c & \img
  \end{tabular}} & & ~\img \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Two sub-question: 1. Is there any reason why you preferred nesting `tabular`s wrt using `multirow`? Most importantly: how does `valign=c` work? I mean, all boxes on the same line are aligned wrt their central line, instead of baseline? In this case, I would expect your last 1-line example (`valign` in both text and image) is the only correct one, but it seems that you mean something else...

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis: 1) `\multirow` inside a `tabular` that uses [`booktabs`](//ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) rules are not always aligned exactly, because the rules inserted via `\midrule` and `\cmidrule` uses extra space above/below. Instead, I just set each component on their own rather than in a big all-inclusive `tabular`. `tabular`s are necessarily vertically aligned at the centre. 2) `valign=c` changes the anchor point from whatever it is for the object to the `v`ertical `c`entre of that object.

Comment: would you be so kind to wrote something more about _but it's not always necessary and **may depend on both elements**_?

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis: Some elements, like `tabular` (or `minipage`) already have a vertically centred anchor point. See ``x \begin{tabular}{c} a \\ b \\ c \end{tabular}``. So, in these cases it's not necessary to `\adjustbox{valign=c}`.